# Is there any way to hide certain PARAMETERS from URL ? I am using LINK. [REACTJS]

Tags: reactjs, url, hyperlink, react-router-dom

I am using `<Link to={/name/id} >name</Link>` to change route;
I have a Route setup as `<Route path="/name/:id" component={Name} />`
with that **Id** i am fetching data

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchName(this.props.match.params.id);
  }
```

but now i have the **Id** being displayed on the **URL** and I do not want to display the **Id** on the **URL**.
So, was wondering if there are any workaround for not displaying the **Id** on the **URL**

Answer (score 0):

The only way to prevent from showing on the URL, is by working with `redux` so you can save the `id` in the store before navigating to the page, and after navigating to the page, you just get it from store. Or you can achieve it by using `sessionStorage`, you save your id in session storage

```
sessionStorage.setItem('my-id', id);
//navigate to other page


//then in other page just use the code below to get that id from session storage.
sessionStorage.getItem('my-id');
```